# ffmpeg: Export to 24 bits wave with Microsoft PCM, not Extensible (with Lavf58.76.100)

Tags: ffmpeg, export, wav

I notice that, when I use FFMPEG to export a mod to a wave in 24 bits or higher, FFMPEG decides to use extensible encoding instead of regular PCM encoding and uses "Lavf58.76.100", whatever that is. I used exiftool to inspect the exported wav, and this is the result:

```
---- File ----
File Type                       : WAV
File Type Extension             : wav
MIME Type                       : audio/x-wav
---- RIFF ----
Encoding                        : Extensible
Num Channels                    : 2
Sample Rate                     : 48000
Avg Bytes Per Sec               : 288000
Bits Per Sample                 : 24
Software                        : Lavf58.76.100
```

The problem is, that many programs don't understand this extensible wav format. Is there any way to tell FFMPEG to use regular PCM instead? I notice that other programs such as the bass library can export to a 24 bit wav using regular PCM encoding.

This is the command I am using:

`ffmpeg -y -loglevel error -f libopenmpt -i c:\temp\sometrack.IT -map_metadata -1 -c:a pcm_s24le c:\temp\sometrack.wav`

**Edit**

While I was writing this question, I was a bit frustrated and lacked knowledge. Now, it's all perfectly clear; wave files with a bit depth higher than 16 bits, should have the WAVE_FORMAT_EXTENSIBLE tag (and it makes sense, see the answer). The software that I was using to render mod files to wave, other than FFmpeg, were not honoring this rule. Thank you, Tom Yan for clarifying.

Comment: None of what you said makes sense to me to be honest. The so called encoding in this exiftool refers to only the structure / type of the wave header. The wave format (extensible or not) doesn't even changes the body of the bitstream at all AFAIK. You should be table to obtain an bit-to-bit identical file as what would be output with `-f s24le` if you cut the header off. Also the wave extensible format has been around like decades ago and was defined by Microsoft just like the original Wave. The whole point is to support > 16-bit and/or multichannel audio.

Comment: Maybe you are talking about https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dd757713(v=vs.85), which is like deprecated variant AFAIK.

Comment: I am a front-end developer, this is a hobby project, don't understand much about audio structures in general, working with bytes, et cetera. That said:
I can't play the 24 bit wave in libraries such as NAudio (only supports 16 bit). Other libraries, (iirKlang) tell me "Wave file has an unsupported format: EXTENSIBLE (only PCM supported currently)". Can't use VLCSharp (32 bit project), can't use Bass (in use for other purposes), long story. The same file exported with Bass library says "Encoding  : Microsoft PCM" and FFMpeg gives "Extensible". So, can FFMpeg export to 24 bit PCM?

Comment: If you insist, you can hack it by removing what would be done for the condition `waveformatextensible`: https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/master/libavformat/riffenc.c Good thing about open source.

Comment: @Tom Yan, "Formats that support more than two channels or sample sizes of more than 16 bits can be described in a WAVEFORMATEXTENSIBLE structure". Does this mean that Bass library is "cheating"? It is a 24 bit wave, and exiftool reports Encoding                        : Microsoft PCM

Comment: If the software / libraries you use support "raw" PCM (which require you to specify the spec of the stream when it is imported / played), you can try adding `-f s24le` before the output filename (and you probably want to use extension name like `.raw` / `.pcm`). And you may also want to see if AIFF is better supported by what you used.

Comment: And thus, if I understand correctly, wave files > 16 bit SHOULD be "waveformatextensible", right? If that is the case, I am not going to "hack" riffenc.c, but look for another solution.

Comment: Aiff is maybe an alternative, good point. Not sure if software supports RAW wav, but something to investigate as well

Comment: Well I suspect it use the header structure of  `WAVEFORMATEX`, which in the more proper case like what ffmpeg output would be a part in a `WAVEFORMATEXTENSIBLE`. Or perhaps it simply "abuse" `WAVEFORMAT` by merely "implying" the audio is 24-bit with `nAvgBytesPerSec`and `nBlockAlign`: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/mmreg/ns-mmreg-waveformat (to be fair software / library can "deduce" the bit depth with their values)

Comment: Yeah I'd say wave format extensible / what ffmpeg output is the proper approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*(Not all of my comments were accurate / correct, so refer to the following if you are interested.)*

*Theoretically* speaking, [`PCMWAVEFORMAT`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/mmeapi/ns-mmeapi-pcmwaveformat) can be used for audio with bit depth higher than 16. The header structure does not pose any limitation that prevents itself from supporting such audio.

However, there are apparently a few reasons that ffmpeg does not write a WAVE header in such format for that kind of audio.

For one, the format has been superseded by [`WAVEFORMATEX`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/mmeapi/ns-mmeapi-waveformatex), and, according to the documentation:

```
...

wBitsPerSample

... If wFormatTag is WAVE_FORMAT_PCM, then wBitsPerSample should be equal to
8 or 16. ...

...
```

In addition to the above requirement, there is no `wFormatTag` value other than `WAVE_FORMAT_EXTENSIBLE` that is defined for PCM audio with bit depth higher than 16.

Whether the "extensions" defined in [`WAVEFORMATEXTENSIBLE`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/mmreg/ns-mmreg-waveformatextensible) can be left out when `wFormatTag` is `WAVE_FORMAT_EXTENSIBLE` is not exactly clear. In [`WAVEFORMATEX`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/mmeapi/ns-mmeapi-waveformatex), it is stated that:

```
...

wFormatTag


... When this structure is included in a WAVEFORMATEXTENSIBLE structure,
this value must be WAVE_FORMAT_EXTENSIBLE. ...

...
```

With such a statement, probably no one would / should assume that it is allowed anyway.

If you read [`WAVEFORMATEX`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/mmeapi/ns-mmeapi-waveformatex) and [`WAVEFORMATEXTENSIBLE`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/mmreg/ns-mmreg-waveformatextensible) carefully, you'll notice that the real reason the latter exists (in terms of bit depth) is, it allows the former to store a multiple-of-8 container size with the "real" sample size being stored in one of the extensions defined in the latter. For example, 24 and 20 respectively for some (nasty) 20-bit PCM stream.

For the record though, the `wav` muxer of ffmpeg does NOT (at least not properly) support the quirky case just mentioned as far as I can see. (Both field would be written with the value of `0`, I think, if such stream is not rejected.)

In case you really need ffmpeg to write the header in the format of `PCMWAVEFORMAT` for some 24-bit audio, you can consider to build it with the following patch:

```
diff --git a/libavformat/riff.h b/libavformat/riff.h
index 85d6786663..5794857f53 100644
--- a/libavformat/riff.h
+++ b/libavformat/riff.h
@@ -57,6 +57,11 @@ void ff_put_bmp_header(AVIOContext *pb, AVCodecParameters *par, int for_asf, int
  */
 #define FF_PUT_WAV_HEADER_SKIP_CHANNELMASK      0x00000002
 
+/**
+ * Tell ff_put_wav_header() not to write WAVEFORMATEXTENSIBLE extensions if possible.
+ */
+#define FF_PUT_WAV_HEADER_FORCE_PCMWAVEFORMAT      0x00000004
+
 /**
  * Write WAVEFORMAT header structure.
  *
diff --git a/libavformat/riffenc.c b/libavformat/riffenc.c
index ffccfa3d48..4dc8ca6e0f 100644
--- a/libavformat/riffenc.c
+++ b/libavformat/riffenc.c
@@ -80,9 +80,9 @@ int ff_put_wav_header(AVFormatContext *s, AVIOContext *pb,
     waveformatextensible = (par->channels > 2 && par->channel_layout) ||
                            par->channels == 1 && par->channel_layout && par->channel_layout != AV_CH_LAYOUT_MONO ||
                            par->channels == 2 && par->channel_layout && par->channel_layout != AV_CH_LAYOUT_STEREO ||
-                           par->sample_rate > 48000 ||
                            par->codec_id == AV_CODEC_ID_EAC3 ||
-                           av_get_bits_per_sample(par->codec_id) > 16;
+                           ((par->sample_rate > 48000 || av_get_bits_per_sample(par->codec_id) > 16) &&
+                            !(flags & FF_PUT_WAV_HEADER_FORCE_PCMWAVEFORMAT));
 
     if (waveformatextensible)
         avio_wl16(pb, 0xfffe);
diff --git a/libavformat/wavenc.c b/libavformat/wavenc.c
index 2317700be1..bd41d6eeb3 100644
--- a/libavformat/wavenc.c
+++ b/libavformat/wavenc.c
@@ -83,6 +83,7 @@ typedef struct WAVMuxContext {
     int peak_block_pos;
     int peak_ppv;
     int peak_bps;
+    int extensible;
 } WAVMuxContext;
 
 #if CONFIG_WAV_MUXER
@@ -324,9 +325,10 @@ static int wav_write_header(AVFormatContext *s)
     }
 
     if (wav->write_peak != PEAK_ONLY) {
+        int flags = !wav->extensible ? FF_PUT_WAV_HEADER_FORCE_PCMWAVEFORMAT : 0;
         /* format header */
         fmt = ff_start_tag(pb, "fmt ");
-        if (ff_put_wav_header(s, pb, s->streams[0]->codecpar, 0) < 0) {
+        if (ff_put_wav_header(s, pb, s->streams[0]->codecpar, flags) < 0) {
             av_log(s, AV_LOG_ERROR, "Codec %s not supported in WAVE format\n",
                    avcodec_get_name(s->streams[0]->codecpar->codec_id));
             return AVERROR(ENOSYS);
@@ -494,6 +496,7 @@ static const AVOption options[] = {
     { "peak_block_size", "Number of audio samples used to generate each peak frame.",   OFFSET(peak_block_size), AV_OPT_TYPE_INT, { .i64 = 256 }, 0, 65536, ENC },
     { "peak_format",     "The format of the peak envelope data (1: uint8, 2: uint16).", OFFSET(peak_format), AV_OPT_TYPE_INT,     { .i64 = PEAK_FORMAT_UINT16 }, PEAK_FORMAT_UINT8, PEAK_FORMAT_UINT16, ENC },
     { "peak_ppv",        "Number of peak points per peak value (1 or 2).",              OFFSET(peak_ppv), AV_OPT_TYPE_INT, { .i64 = 2 }, 1, 2, ENC },
+    { "extensible",      "Write WAVEFORMATEXTENSIBLE extensions.",                      OFFSET(extensible), AV_OPT_TYPE_BOOL, { .i64 = 1 }, 0, 1, ENC },
     { NULL },
 };
```

Then by adding `-extensible 0` before the output file path / name, you should be able to get what you called a "regular" 24-bit WAVE file.

Comment: Thank you for sharing your in depth knowledge. Now I understand what is going on, and your patch is much appreciated.